# How Can i alter admin setting?

Tags: drupal

I want to add one text field in  the /civicrm/admin/setting/mapping.
How can i add text field in admin mapping setting page ? I have override the mapping tpl in my custom location.
[image]

Comment: may help folk  if you explain the purpose/outcome

Comment: Basically I want to add Tom-tom map with civicrm on some pages. So i need to add one text field for save Tom-tom map API key on mapping page like google map field . which one i will used anywhere in the civicrm .